# check for duplicate date from data and assign to new one json

Tags: json

i have a json which contain duplicate date , i want to merge duplicate date into single json object.
Data:

```
 [
   {"date":"2017-06-26","mac":"66"},
   {"date":"2017-06-26","window":"400"},
   {"date":"2017-07-03","mac":"19"},
   {"date":"2017-07-03","window":"12"}
 ]
```

output should be:

```
  [
   {"date":"2017-06-26","mac":"66","window":"400"},
   {"date":"2017-07-03","mac":"19","window":"12"}
 ]
```

Comment: what have you tried ? You can use json libraries to achieve this.

Comment: also what language you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a javascript function that does that, you can apply JSON.stringify(...) to the output after passing your array and obtain the new json.

```
(( a ) => { 
    // used to check for already inserted dates
    let withoutDupes = { };

    if(Array.isArray(a)) {
        a.forEach( (item) => { 
            // assuming item has a "date" property inside
            if(withoutDupes[item.date]) {
                withoutDupes[item.date] = Object.assign( item, withoutDupes[item.date] );
            } else {
                withoutDupes[item.date] = item;
            }
        } );
    }

    return Object.values( withoutDupes );
})( a )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `jq` [command line parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and its `group_by` function:

```
jq '[group_by(.date)|.[]|add]' file
[
  {
    "date": "2017-06-26",
    "mac": "66",
    "window": "400"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-07-03",
    "mac": "19",
    "window": "12"
  }
]
```